# Why is knitr unable to find framed.sty or kpsewhich?

Tags: r, latex, knitr

```
knit('test2.rnw')


processing file: test2.rnw
  |>>>>>>>>>>>>>                                                    |  20%
  |>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                                       |  40%
label: setup (with options) 
List of 2
 $ include: logi FALSE
 $ cache  : logi FALSE

sh: kpsewhich: command not found
  |>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                          |  60%
  |>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>             |  80%
  |>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>| 100%
  ordinary text without R code


output file: /Users/xxx/Desktop/R_meetup/documentation/test2.tex

Warning message:
In test_latex_pkg("framed", system.file("misc", "framed.sty", package = "knitr")) :
  unable to find LaTeX package 'framed'; will use a copy from knitr
 >
```

I'm on OSX Lion 10.7.3

Path for kpsewhich:

```
   $ which kpsewhich
    /usr/texbin/kpsewhich


$ which pdflatex
/usr/texbin/pdflatex
```

Both paths are in my `.bash_profile` in my `home` directory. I do have the framed package in my Tex install.

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/texbin/pdflatex
PATH=$PATH:/usr/texbin/kpsewhich
export PATH
```

**Solution**

Adding this to my `.rprofile` fixed it:

`Sys.setenv("PATH" = paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"),"/usr/texbin",sep=":"))`

Comment: what is the output of `kpsewhich framed.sty` if you run it directly in the terminal?

Comment: `kpsewhich framed.sty

./framed.sty`

Comment: no no, you should run this command elsewhere since `framed.sty` is under the current directory

Comment: oh right. `kpsewhich framed.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/framed/framed.sty`

Comment: Solution: Adding this to my `.rprofile` fixed it: `Sys.setenv("PATH" = paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"),"/usr/texbin",sep=":"))`

Comment: yes, that is indeed a solution, but I'm wondering why R does not respect your bash profile; I remember it is `~/.bashrc` (at least I use this file to change my `PATH` under Ubuntu), but `~/.bash_profile` might also work; I do not know

Comment: I'm having exactly this problem, too, on OSX Sierra but @Maiasaura 's solution didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Just FYI, now `knitr` will automatically add `/tex/texbin` to `PATH` for Mac OS if it is not already in `PATH`.

Answer (score 3):

Installing `texlive-latex-extra` solved for me. The original answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/25517332/1169233) is intended for Ubuntu, but AFAIK it should work verbatim on Mac OS too.