# RStudio on OSX Markdown Preview PDF Gives Pandoc Error 43

Tags: r, macos, pdf, rstudio, pandoc

I am on OSX Mavericks and have the newest version of RStudio (0.98.994), R (3.1.1) and MacTex 2014 (25 May 2014). All R packages have been updated. When I try to preview a markdown file as a PDF, I get the following error:

```
/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc/pandoc README.utf8.md --to latex --from        markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash-implicit_figures --output README.pdf --template /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmd/latex/default.tex --highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex --variable geometry:margin=1in 
pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source.

Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
Execution halted
```

I don't know what I have done wrong but this simply doesn't work.

Comment: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/202294857-Bug-in-standard-LaTeX-template-0-98-932-

Comment: I should mention that the same R and RStudio set up with MikTeX on Windows 7 works just fine so I don't think this is the problem

Comment: Regardless, it's likely that this question can really only be addressed by RStudio support.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this same error while trying to use a markdown template, papaja, on a mac (OS X), even though I had the full version of MacTex installed.

What ultimately fixed the problem for me was installing pandoc on my computer: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/

As soon as I installed it, I was able to knit the markdown file into a PDF. Hopefully, this solution works for you, too!

Answer (score -1):

You might need to install framed latex package. see the following links

[PDF rendering in Rmarkdown2/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24314086/pdf-rendering-in-rmarkdown2)

https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/39

Comment: Nope, that package is installed. In fact I did a full install of every package MacTeX has to offer.