# Knit PDf file from RStudio

Tags: r, linux, markdown

I am trying to Knit PDf file from RStudio, and I am getting the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `framed.sty' not found.
```

---

- R version: 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
- Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu on AWS EC2

Comment: You need to include more details about your session - R version and operating system. Presumably the instance is running Ubuntu? If so, you will need to install a LaTeX backend - e.g. `sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra`.

Comment: R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
 platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu

Comment: Have you tried searching for an answer on the internet? What about these answers? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24314086/pdf-rendering-in-rmarkdown2 https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/39 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9590134/why-is-knitr-unable-to-find-framed-sty-or-kpsewhich

Answer (score 33):

I know this is kind of old, but I tried all this answers in my ubuntu and it didn't work, finally I found that yihui developed the [tinytex package](https://yihui.name/tinytex/), the only thing you have to do is run the following code:

```
install.packages(c('tinytex', 'rmarkdown'))
tinytex::install_tinytex()
```

and you are set, this works cross platform

Cheers

Comment: I have used this today to solve a similar problem. Pretty straightforward solution.

Answer (score 19):

While trying to knit PDF file from R Studio.

**Error-1:** ! LaTeX Error: File `framed.sty' not found.

**Reference:** https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/39

**Solution:**

You need to install the framed LaTeX package.

```
yum -y install texlive-framed
```

**Error-2:** ! LaTeX Error: File `titling.sty' not found.

**Reference:** https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/359

**Solution:**

```
wget http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titling.zip

unzip titling.zip     # (might need to sudo yum install unzip)

cd titling

latex titling.ins

sudo mkdir -p /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titling

sudo cp titling.sty /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titling/

sudo texhash
```

Comment: The first works for me on fedora 31.

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar problem with **titling.sty**. The solution was to install a package that contained the missing file.

## Ubuntu:

On my ubuntu it was:

```
sudo apt install texlive-latex-extra
```

Remember, that you can always find a package that contains a given file by using apt-file:

```
sudo apt-file search titling.sty
```

Of course, you'll have to install the apt-file package first (and refresh the file database) if you haven't done it before:

```
sudo apt install apt-file
sudo apt-file update
```

Answer (score 1):

After resolving the framed.sty issue, I was able to resolve the titling.sty error with:

> sudo yum -y install texlive-titling

Answer (score 0):

Based on your platform, I suspect the least disruptive solution is similar to that for Fedora.  I say "least disruptive," because I did not have to replace TexLive with a different package, I just added the missing components. The process I followed came from a solution posted to  https://askbot.fedoraproject.org/en/answers/94766/revisions/ [note that the page has moved so this is only read only], but nonetheless; it explains why Fedora does not ship with all the  TexLive components and more importantly - it explains how to load them separately. For example, from your terminal, the following will install the missing "framed.sty" component: sudo dnf install "tex(framed.sty)"

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions (including using sudo tlmgr or tinytex) worked for me on macOS Monterey.

Installing texlive through Homebrew and relinking fixed it.

```
brew install texlive
brew link --overwrite texlive
```