# Error when running knitr: sh: kpsewhich: command not found

Tags: r, compiler-errors, latex, knitr, sweave

I have the code below in a `.Rnw` file called `minimal.Rnw`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\date{\today}

\section{Header}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\end{document}
```

When I run `knit("minimal.Rnw")` on the file, I get this warning message and error:

```
Warning message:
In test_latex_pkg("framed", system.file("misc", "framed.sty", package = "knitr")) :
  unable to find LaTeX package 'framed'; will use a copy from knitr
sh: kpsewhich: command not found
```

Does anyone know what's going wrong?

Comment: See the following thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9590134/why-is-knitr-unable-to-find-framed-sty-or-kpsewhich

Comment: I ran `Sys.setenv("PATH" = paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"),"/usr/texbin",sep=":"))` in R but this did not get rid of the message `sh: kpsewhich: command not found`

Comment: What is the output of `Sys.getenv('PATH')`? Where did you run `knit()`? In the terminal or RStudio? If the latter, what is its version (if not the latest, please try to upgrade)? MacTeX no longer writes symlinks of executables to `/usr/texbin`, so it won't help if you are using the latest version of MacTeX, and it is not necessary to change the PATH variable in R if you are using the latest version of RStudio.

Comment: I'm having the same problem on OSX Sierra and the proposed solution didn't work for me, either. The framed package is showing up as installed in TeX Live Utility.